# How do I fix a RVM install that was done using SUDO

Tags: rvm

A member of our team installed RVM using sudo. We removed `~/.rvm` and `/usr/local/rvm` but we are unable to install RVM.

This :

```
bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

Gives the following error:

```
mkdir: /usr/local/rvm: Permission denied
```

Which is weird, since we are not using sudo this time.

Am not sure where could be the error. What could I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove also

```
/etc/rvmrc
```

directory and then install RVM

Should Success install !!!