# rvm installation - /usr/local/rvm : permission denied (Before this, I deleted home directory by mistake in Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a RVM install that was done using SUDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999439/how-do-i-fix-a-rvm-install-that-was-done-using-sudo)

I have created a user on my server 'myuser' . Logged into it and ran this cmd :

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --auto-dotfiles
```

Everything fine and installed correctly.

Bymistake, I deleted the home directory using another user login, i.e /home/myuser (where rvm is installed) (logged in by other user 'anothuser').

Then lost rvm, so tried running the same install cmd , but now got this error :

```
    curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --auto-dotfiles
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  100   185  100   185    0     0    349      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1094
  100 10956  100 10956    0     0  10248      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 10248
 Turning on auto dotfiles mode.
  mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm': Permission denied
```

So, I deleted the user , created again the same user and ran this command again, but again the same error .

Comment: user should be `sudo` user

Comment: You need to clarify `whoami` when you run your commands, and show `ls -lad $HOME` before anyone can help you.

Comment: did you create home directory for new user and setup permission correctly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to clean old installation:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh /usr/local/rvm
```

and restart to clean all loaded shell environment - it is required step

Comment: Thanks for this and especially for the restart note, I've been chasing my tail around like crazy until I found your answer.