# Why do I get permissions errors installing RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, bash

I followed the RVM installation manual, and found that my system meets the minimum requirements for installation.

I included the user in `/etc/sudoers`.

Then I ran:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash-s stable - autolibs = homebrew - rails
```

but the installation process returned:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:100   184  100   184    0     0    156      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   229
 46 15779   46  7325    0     0   4433      0  0:00:03  0:00:01  0:100 15779  100 15779    0     0   9547      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 8255k
Please read and follow further instructions.
Press ENTER to continue.
bash: line 584: /usr/local/rvm/RELEASE: Permission denied`
```

What is it I'm doing wrong? I also read other comments on this forum, that said it is correct to install RVM from the console as a user, not root, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Comment: This isn't off-topic for Stack Overflow, because it is a direct question about a commonly used programming tool for Ruby. User permission problems with RVM are also commonly answered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you want RVM to be available for all users on your system? Use `sudo` if so. If your system is a single user system, do NOT use `sudo`. RVM is recommended as a single-user solution by the authors, though it can work for multiple users, and single-user is the path of least resistance. Read http://rvm.io/rvm/install carefully and completely, BEFORE trying to install. Oh. Wait. You already tried to install. Read http://rvm.io/rvm/install carefully and completely, AFTER trying to install.

Comment: i only want acces to my user -NOT in root, only user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you do not run the command as root.

Try `sudo curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash-s stable - autolibs = homebrew - rails`.

EDIT:

Ok, i just see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153005/rvm-installation-usr-local-rvm-permission-denied-before-this-i-deleted-ho).
This issue can be due to oldest rvm installation and to solve it, you need to clean oldest installation.

To do that: `sudo rm -rf /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh /usr/local/rvm`
Then, rerun your install command line.

Hope it will work.

Comment: yes, i did it as user. I've tried with sudo and the result is the same: the same error.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Because rvm try to write at /usr/local/rvm and it requires sudo privilege. So, it outputs an error since you had ran the command as sample user.

Comment: Do NOT use `sudo` with RVM for single-user installations; Only use it for multi-users. Using `sudo` without fully understanding how RVM works and what escalating privileges does is a sure-fire path to permission-error town.

Comment: also when you run sudo like the above only curl runs as root.  bash will run as you.. And as the @theTinMan says, you should only use sudo for system installs.  are you on osx or linux? i thought homebrew was osx only (there is experimental fork for linux).

Comment: Ok, i've just edited my answer after finding a possible duplicate topic.

Comment: I read the three possible alternatives out there for installing RVM. The first is to understand users and say the same thing (tin man).
I have Linux installed. And I modified sudoers file to add my user with sudo permissions.
Should I reset the sudoers file?

Comment: Still the same after reseting your sudoers file ou after cleaning oldest installation as i suggest in my edit?

Comment: I have not reset anything yet. Expecting confirmation any indication, it sounds silly but I prefer not to make changes to get crazy without knowing what I'm doing.
The truth is that I have not at all clear. Include my user in the sudoers file gives you permission to view and write about certain system files but ...
1 what happens if I remove it? (which is as easy as putting it)
2 able to operate with ruby on rails usually from the user account?
3 is due to the access restriction?

Comment: Did you try to clean previous installation of RVM? I've read some topic with the same issue and it sounds like the source of your problem is that (as i said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18987011/1939604))

Comment: is this the topic of which you speak. Or are you kidding me or do not know where you write or maybe, you know too much.
Whatever the problem persists.